# probability - fair coin - simple problem

Tags: probability

In a book I am reading I find this problem:

> Suppose we toss a fair coin until we get exactly two heads. Describe
> the sample space S. What is the probability that exactly k tosses are
> required?

I can describe the sample space correctly, I think.

I think the sample space is the set:
$S = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$, where
(1) $N \ge 2$
(2) $x_N = H$
(3) $x_m = H$ for exactly one $m$ from the set $\{1,2,...,N-1\}$
(4) $x_l = T$ for all $l$ from the set $\{1,2,...,N-1\}$ but $m$

I solved the probability question in 2-3 different ways each time getting a different answer so I am not sure if I am right or wrong. Does this problem refer to conditional probability in any way, or it's simpler than I think? Unfortunately I don't find a solution in the book in order to check my answers. Could anyone provide an authoritative solution?

Comment: I don't know why I got back to this question... Shouldn't the probability be: $\frac{ \frac{k-1}{2^k} } {\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{i-1}{2^i}}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For exactly $k$ tosses to be required, this means the $k$-th toss must be heads, and among the $k-1$ previous tosses there was exactly one toss coming up heads.
The probability of this event, since all tosses are independent, is,
$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot \binom{k-1}{1} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-2} = \frac{k-1}{2^k}
$$
where the first factor is for the $k$-th, and the second part amounts to the $(k-1)$ possibilities to get exactly one Heads amongt $k-1$ tosses.

Comment: This is one of the answers I got too :) How sure are you that this is what's needed here? No conditional probability involved?

Comment: Since the tosses are independent, conditional probabilities should not come into play (the conditioning would "disappear") -- what sort of conditioning were you thinking of?

Comment: I was thinking conditional like maybe: what is the probability we need k tosses exactly provided that we get 2 heads exactly (with the described experiment)? But I had hard time formalizing this and just got swamped in my own thoughts.

Comment: Your sample space looks correct to me. I also don't think thinking in conditional probabilities would help here -- again, at the end of the day I think that you'll end up applying Baye's rule, getting a variant of the above, and simplifying the conditionings because of independence.

Comment: I don't know why I got back to this question... But... shouldn't the probability actually be: $\frac{ \frac{k-1}{2^k} } {\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{i-1}{2^i}}$ ?

Comment: Meaning ... we have multiple ways to get exactly $2$ heads, we can get them on the $i$-th try for $i = 2,3,4,...$. Getting the two heads on the $k$-th try is just one way.

Comment: Oh the denominator in the expression I wrote is $1$. So we're left with the numerator anyway. OK, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any sample is of the form $t\cdots tht\cdots th$. Note that the only fixed thing here must be that your last toss is heads. Therefore, the chance that exactly $k$ tosses are required is the chance that you throw $k-2$ times tails and once heads, and once heads as a last throw. The probaility of that equals $(k-1)0.5^{k-2}\cdot0.5\cdot0.5$.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this is the most simple answer I came up with too. Thanks. Seems 2 persons are providing this solution (3 including myself) so that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Negative Binomial distribution.  Look it up on wikipedia.

Comment: I doubt it. This problem comes right after the 1st book chapter which is a chapter just about simple probabilities only (incl. conditional and bayes probability).

Comment: Well it is the negative binomial, whether you have learned that or not.  If you look up the domain and prob distribution function for the negative binomial you'll have the answers you need

Comment: @peter.petrov: you don't *need* the Negative Binomial, but it's a quick way to derive the result (it is a distribution capturing exactly what you want).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.